# How can I get this code to run quietly in the background?

Tags: excel, vba

My code attempts to loop through a series of data points pulled from a server (PIcurrVal function), and react to the "random" input of a certain string into one of these data points by grabbing some related values and placing them into an excel document in the order in which the chosen string is inputted. This process will be overwritten every 24 hours. My code here achieves this goal, but feels clunky and renders the file unusable while running. How can I streamline this operation to run neatly in the background?

```
Sub culturestop_timestamp()

Dim culstop As String

Dim MFA As Variant
Dim MFB As Variant
Dim MFC As Variant
Dim MFD As Variant
Dim MFE As Variant
Dim MFF As Variant
Dim MFG As Variant
Dim MFH As Variant

Dim MFAR As Variant
Dim MFBR As Variant
Dim MFCR As Variant
Dim MFDR As Variant
Dim MFER As Variant
Dim MFFR As Variant
Dim MFGR As Variant
Dim MFHR As Variant

Dim MFAT As String
Dim MFBT As String
Dim MFCT As String
Dim MFDT As String
Dim MFET As String
Dim MFFT As String
Dim MFGT As String
Dim MFHT As String

Dim A As Integer
Dim B As Integer
Dim C As Integer
Dim D As Integer
Dim E As Integer
Dim F As Integer
Dim G As Integer
Dim H As Integer

Dim start As Date
Dim curtime As Date


Dim rownum As Integer

Application.OnTime Now, "culturestop_timestamp"
'reset:
'Application.OnTime TimeValue("07:30:00", "culturestop_timestamp")
start = Now()


culstop = "CULSTOP"

rownum = 30

A = 0
B = 0
C = 0
D = 0
E = 0
F = 0
G = 0
H = 0


Do While curtime <= (start + TimeValue("23:59:00"))





    MFA = Application.Run("PICurrVal", "TAPS1.MNFERMA_UNIT/PHASE_SELECT.CVS", 1, "")
    MFB = Application.Run("PICurrVal", "TAPS1.MNFERMB_UNIT/PHASE_SELECT.CVS", 1, "")
    MFC = Application.Run("PICurrVal", "TAPS1.MNFERMC_UNIT/PHASE_SELECT.CVS", 1, "")
    MFD = Application.Run("PICurrVal", "TAPS1.MNFERMD_UNIT/PHASE_SELECT.CVS", 1, "")
    MFE = Application.Run("PICurrVal", "TAPS1.MNFERME_UNIT/PHASE_SELECT.CVS", 1, "")
    MFF = Application.Run("PICurrVal", "TAPS1.MNFERMF_UNIT/PHASE_SELECT.CVS", 1, "")
    MFG = Application.Run("PICurrVal", "TAPS1.MNFERMG_UNIT/PHASE_SELECT.CVS", 1, "")
    MFH = Application.Run("PICurrVal", "TAPS1.MNFERMH_UNIT/PHASE_SELECT.CVS", 1, "")
    If A = 2 Then
        MFA(2) = "Already_Brothed_Out_Today"
    End If
    If B = 2 Then
        MFB(2) = "Already_Brothed_Out_Today"
    End If
    If C = 2 Then
        MFC(2) = "Already_Brothed_Out_Today"
    End If
    If D = 2 Then
        MFD(2) = "Already_Brothed_Out_Today"
    End If
    If E = 2 Then
        MFE(2) = "Already_Brothed_Out_Today"
    End If
    If F = 2 Then
        MFF(2) = "Already_Brothed_Out_Today"
    End If
    If G = 2 Then
        MFG(2) = "Already_Brothed_Out_Today"
    End If
    If H = 2 Then
        MFH(2) = "Already_Brothed_Out_Today"
    End If

    If MFA(2) = culstop Then
        A = 2
        MFAR = Application.Run("PICurrVal", "TAPS1.TC02_RECIPE/MNFERMA_TYPE.CV", 1, "")
        'MFAT = Now()
        Sheet1.Range("A" & rownum) = MFA(1)
        Sheet1.Range("B" & rownum) = MFAR(2)
        'Sheet1.Range("C" & rownum) = 'batchnumber...
        'Sheet1.Range("D" & rownum) =
        'Sheet1.Range("E" & rownum) =
        'Sheet1.Range("F" & rownum) =


        rownum = rownum + 1

    End If

    If MFB(2) = culstop Then
        B = 2
        MFBR = Application.Run("PICurrVal", "TAPS1.TC02_RECIPE/MNFERMB_TYPE.CV", 1, "")
        'MFBT = Now()
        Sheet1.Range("A" & rownum) = MFB(1)
        Sheet1.Range("B" & rownum) = MFBR(2)
        'Sheet1.Range("C" & rownum) =
        'Sheet1.Range("D" & rownum) =
        'Sheet1.Range("E" & rownum) =
        'Sheet1.Range("F" & rownum) =
        rownum = rownum + 1


    End If

    If MFC(2) = culstop Then
        C = 2
        MFCR = Application.Run("PICurrVal", "TAPS1.TC02_RECIPE/MNFERMC_TYPE.CV", 1, "")
        'MFCT = Now()
        Sheet1.Range("A" & rownum) = MFC(1)
        Sheet1.Range("B" & rownum) = MFCR(2)
        'Sheet1.Range("C" & rownum) =
        'Sheet1.Range("D" & rownum) =
        'Sheet1.Range("E" & rownum) =
        'Sheet1.Range("F" & rownum) =
        rownum = rownum + 1


    End If

    If MFD(2) = culstop Then
        D = 2
        MFDR = Application.Run("PICurrVal", "TAPS1.TC02_RECIPE/MNFERMD_TYPE.CV", 1, "")
        'MFDT = Now()
        Sheet1.Range("A" & rownum) = MFD(1)
        Sheet1.Range("B" & rownum) = MFDR(2)
        'Sheet1.Range("C" & rownum) =
        'Sheet1.Range("D" & rownum) =
        'Sheet1.Range("E" & rownum) =
        'Sheet1.Range("F" & rownum) =
        rownum = rownum + 1

    End If

    If MFE(2) = culstop Then
        E = 2
        MFER = Application.Run("PICurrVal", "TAPS1.TC02_RECIPE/MNFERME_TYPE.CV", 1, "")
        'MFET = Now()
        Sheet1.Range("A" & rownum) = MFE(1)
        Sheet1.Range("B" & rownum) = MFER(2)
        'Sheet1.Range("C" & rownum) =
        'Sheet1.Range("D" & rownum) =
        'Sheet1.Range("E" & rownum) =
        'Sheet1.Range("F" & rownum) =
        rownum = rownum + 1

    End If

    If MFF(2) = culstop Then
        F = 2
        MFFR = Application.Run("PICurrVal", "TAPS1.TC02_RECIPE/MNFERMF_TYPE.CV", 1, "")
        'MFFT = Now()
        Sheet1.Range("A" & rownum) = MFF(1)
        Sheet1.Range("B" & rownum) = MFFR(2)
        'Sheet1.Range("C" & rownum) =
        'Sheet1.Range("D" & rownum) =
        'Sheet1.Range("E" & rownum) =
        'Sheet1.Range("F" & rownum) =
        rownum = rownum + 1

    End If

    If MFG(2) = culstop Then
        G = 2
        MFGR = Application.Run("PICurrVal", "TAPS1.TC02_RECIPE/MNFERMG_TYPE.CV", 1, "")
        'MFGT = Now()
        Sheet1.Range("A" & rownum) = MFG(1)
        Sheet1.Range("B" & rownum) = MFGR(2)
        'Sheet1.Range("C" & rownum) =
        'Sheet1.Range("D" & rownum) =
        'Sheet1.Range("E" & rownum) =
        'Sheet1.Range("F" & rownum) =
        rownum = rownum + 1

    End If
    If MFH(2) = culstop Then
        H = 2
        MFHR = Application.Run("PICurrVal", "TAPS1.TC02_RECIPE/MNFERMH_TYPE.CV", 1, "")
        'MFHT = Now()
        Sheet1.Range("A" & rownum) = MFH(1)
        Sheet1.Range("B" & rownum) = MFHR(2)
        'Sheet1.Range("C" & rownum) =
        'Sheet1.Range("D" & rownum) =
        'Sheet1.Range("E" & rownum) =
        'Sheet1.Range("F" & rownum) =
        rownum = rownum + 1

    End If

    curtime = Now()
    'MsgBox ("loop done dawg")
    Loop
    'GoTo reset

End Sub
```

Comment: Please don't put a wall of declarations at the start of your code. Declare variables close to their usage. It makes code so much easier to read.

Comment: thanks for the input

Comment: Can  more than one test in these Ifs be True e.g. can  MFA(2) = culstop and also MFB(2) ?

Comment: Yes, or else I would have done a series of if/else. I am tracking when some fermenters have stopped the digital logic controlling their fermentation before sending to next area of our processes. These culture stop events only happen about 5 times a day but may overlap on occasion.

Comment: if your code works consider posting on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) - just be sure to review their rules on posting.

Comment: I'd port the entire thing to VBScript (or some other language), then run it from the Windows Task Scheduler. Excel really isn't intended to be run as a "service", and it doesn't really strike me as something that would be horribly stable in the long term.

Comment: Looking at all the repetition here, a base review of the logic is called for.